# How often are the regional mirrors of ubuntu updated?

Tags: mirrors

Local servers means a server in different countries like in nepal np.archieve.ubuntu.com
How often are they sync with the main server to update the packages and ISOs ?

Answer (score 4):

[Here is a list of mirrors](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors) where it also mentions how up to date it is.

> How often are the local servers of ubuntu updated?

It depends on the local server. They pull the software in at their convenience.

But specific to Nepal (you have 1 mirror): [Nepal Telecom](http://ubuntu.ntc.net.np/ubuntu/) is one day behind for Yakkaty Yak and up to date for all other releases.

If you look at my country below it (Netherlands; 16 mirrors) it shows a mix of "up to date", "one day behind", "1 week behind" and even "unkown".